# 'ignored' error when mounting fstab entries

Tags: mount, nfs

I'm trying to diagnose why I can't get fstab to mount a path on a remote machine. I can mount, umount and use it perfectly using the following command in bash:

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=3 192.168.1.100:/media/alex/2TB/stuff nfs -o nolock
```

so I'm happy it's configured properly on the server and client.  But using:

```
sudo mount -av
```

tells me that the mount from fstab is ignored.  I've searched a lot of sites and tried all sorts of fstab options but none of them work.  I'm not finding anything online/in man mount which explains why it's ignored. I'm not seeing any useful error messages in any log files.

Some details: the server is up and running when I try the mount.  Actually booting the client fails. The server is a desktop running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the client is a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian and is fully up to date.  I actually got the fstab entry working on a previous OSMC install and I'm kicking myself for not taking a note of it.  I don't remember it being very different from anything I've tried since.

Comment: Can you add some output from the diagnosis steps you have tried? The content of your fstab would also help. And what command you are using to mount it manually.

Comment: Thanks for the question. I'll post the failing fstab entry when I am home later on today.  I've tried about 20 variations though.